# RegEx and HTML: How to match an element "foo", which contains at least two other elements "bar"? (negative look ahead assertion)

Tags: html, regex, regex-lookarounds

I like to match the element "table" which has the class "zot" and contains at least two elements "td".
A table e.g. which contains only "th" but no "td" should not be matched.

I tried the following expression without success:

```
<table class="zot">([\S\s]*?(?!\/table>)<td){2,}
```

The same expression in more readable free spacing syntax:

```
<table class="zot"> # literal
(                   # begin of group
[\S\s]              # non whitespace or whitespace
*                   # quantifier
?                   # greediness modificator
(?!\/table>)        # negative look ahead assertion with the literal "/table>" 
<td                 # literal
)                   # end of group
{2,}                # quantifier
```

Probably my understanding of the negative lookahead is wrong.

I created a code pen for the case: https://regexr.com/43mmh

What is my mistake, please? Thanks.

Below you find my HTML code for the test (the same as in the code pen):

```
<table class="zot">
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<p>Lorem</p>
<table class="zot">
        <tr>
            <th>e</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>f</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table class="zot">
        <tr>
            <th>g</th>
            <th>h</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>i</td>
            <td>j</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Which matches do I wish to have?

```
<table class="zot">
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td
```

and

```
<table class="zot">
    <tr>
        <th>g</th>
        <th>h</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td
```

Comment: What language are you working with? Using regex to parse HTML isn't a great idea. Is "foo" guaranteed to come before "bar"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `foo` to come before `bar`, you can use

```
<table class="zot">((?!\/table>).)+foo(?1)+bar(?1)+<\/table>
```

https://regexr.com/43nkb

The general idea is to repeat any character which isn't the `/` in `/table>`, match `foo`, repeat the previous pattern again, match `bar`, match the previous pattern again, and finally match the end table tag.

Note the `s` flag and the use of `(?1)` syntax, which makes the regex a lot easier to read. Without that, you'll have to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`, and type out the first subpattern manually instead of the `(?1)`s, eg

```
<table class="zot">(?:(?!\/table>)[\s\S])+foo(?:(?!\/table>)[\s\S])+bar(?:(?!\/table>)[\s\S])+<\/table>
```

That said, if at all possible, in whatever environment you're using, it would likely be more elegant to use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't mentioned "foo" and "bar" in the regex because that is only a placeholder for text.
I only want to know how many tables in my site contain more than one td. Independent of any other contents.

I will edit my question and mark, which match I like to have.

Answer (score 0):

I have totally rewritten my answer, now you will get `1 match per table` with more than one table cell.

**The regex**:

```
<table class="zot">(?:(?:[\S\s](?!\/table>))*?<td){2,}[\S\s]*?<\/table>
```

**Explanation:**

`<table class="zot">` matches the literal string `<table class="zot">`.

`(?:` creates a non capturing Group.

`(?:` creates a non capturing Group.

`[\S\s]` matches Space and non Space (everything) one time.

`(?!\/table>)` creates a negative look ahead for: '`/table`'.

`*?` This Group is matched zero or more times - non greedy.

`<td` matches the literal string `<td`.

`{2,}` The outer Group is matched 2 or more times.

`[\S\s]*?` matches anything zero or more times.

`<\/table>` matches the literal string `<\/table>`

You need to set the `'global'` flag.

Now you get one match per table that contains at least `2 table cells`.

You can test it [Regexr](https://regexr.com/43v29) or [Here](http://bak-o-soft.dk/RegEx/JSRegExBuilder.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But you missunderstood me. I didn't mention other strings but "td>" in the regex, because there are many different structures of tables in the documents I want to search through.

I hope there's a solution for the task. Thanks.